# Get Results from mySQL in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am trying to get result from as table in mySQL in the following code.
It does not work. I am newbie in PHP.

Maybe someone can help whatws wrong in my code? I think that my SQL sentence is not written well. Is it?

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: text/html; charset=utf8");

// header('Content-Type:text/html;charset=utf-8');

//1. create connection

$connection=mysql_connect("localhost","user","pass");

if(!$connection){
    die("database connection failed:" . mysql_error());
}

//2. select database 

$db = mysql_select_db("database",$connection);

if(!db) {
    die("database connection failed:" . mysql_error());
}

//if i want to work with hebrew databases

mysql_query("SET NAMES 'utf8'",$connection); // reading heberer from phpadmin database - only for hebrew sites 

$MessageNo = $_POST['MsgNo']

//$MessageN0=(int)$MessageNo

$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MessageContent WHERE MsgNo='$MessageNo'");;;

$messages = array();

while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($query)) {
    $messages[] = array('MsgContId' => $row['MsgContId'], 'MsgNo' => $row['MsgNo'],'MsgContent' => $row['MsgContent'], 'AddedBy' => $row['AddedBy'],'AddedAt'=>$row['AddedAt']);
}

// echo json_encode(array('users' => $users));

echo json_encode($messages);

mysql_close($connection);

?>
```

Comment: you've many syntax errors which is off-topic. This http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php will help you to figure out what they are.

Comment: Please, [stop using `mysql_*` functions](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12859942/why-shouldnt-i-use-mysql-functions-in-php). They are no longer maintained and are [officially deprecated](https://wiki.php.net/rfc/mysql_deprecation). Learn about [prepared statements](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prepared_statement) instead, and use [PDO](http://jayblanchard.net/demystifying_php_pdo.html).

Answer (score 1):

I can see on this line you have formatting errors:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MessageContent WHERE MsgNo='$MessageNo'");;;
```

Remove the extra two semi-colons:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MessageContent WHERE MsgNo='$MessageNo'");
```

Also this:

```
$MessageNo = $_POST['MsgNo']
```

Needs a semi-colon:

```
$MessageNo = $_POST['MsgNo'];
```

Additionally you're using deprecated functions. I would suggest you look into MySQLi functions or PDO.

Consult: [**`mysqli` with prepared statements**](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php), or [**PDO with prepared statements**](http://php.net/pdo.prepared-statements).

EDIT: Also in your second query, you're not using the connection string:

```
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM MessageContent WHERE MsgNo='$MessageNo'",$connection);
```

---

Add [**error reporting**](http://php.net/manual/en/function.error-reporting.php) to the top of your file(s) which will help find errors.

```
<?php 
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

// rest of your code
```

**Sidenote:** Error reporting should only be done in staging, and never production.

- Also add `or die(mysql_error())` to `mysql_query()`.

---

**Sidenote:**

- Your present code is open to [**SQL injection**](https://stackoverflow.com/q/60174/).